# How to sum distinct rows in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to add a new column with the sum of the values of another column, but only for distinct rows.
Say we have this dataframe:

```
    col1     col2   vote
0     a        2     5
1     a        2     5
2     b        2     2
3     c        4     1
4     d        3     5
5     d        3     5
6     d        3     5
```

I want to group by col2, and then sum all the votes of distinct pairs of col1 and col 2 (the vote is always the same for each pair of  col1 and col2.

I'm trying to obtain this result:

```
    col1     col2   vote   aggrVote
0     a        2     5        7
1     a        2     5        7
2     b        2     2        7
3     c        4     1        1
4     d        3     5        5
5     d        3     5        5
6     d        3     5        5
```

The value 3 for col2 has only one distinct col1's value, so the vote is just 5. the value 2 for col2 has 3 distinct col1's values (a,b) so the sum is 5 + 2

Comment: the input dataframe has wrong data for col2 where col1 is c, it should be 4 instead of 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2']).groupby('col2')['vote'].sum() #thanks @jez
df['aggrVote']=df.col2.map(s)
print(df)
```

---

```
  col1  col2  vote  aggrVote
0    a     2     5         7
1    a     2     5         7
2    b     2     2         7
3    c     4     1         1
4    d     3     5         5
5    d     3     5         5
6    d     3     5         5
```

Comment: `s = df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2']).groupby('col2')['vote'].sum()`

Comment: for col1 and col2 should I put the column name instead? Thank you

Comment: @natsumiyu yes, if your column name has spaces, then don't use the dot notation. replace `df.col2.map` with `df['col2'].map`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it all in one line:

```
df
#  col1  col2  vote
#0    a     2     5
#1    a     2     5
#2    b     2     2
#3    c     4     1
#4    d     3     5
#5    d     3     5
#6    d     3     5

df['aggrVote'] = df.groupby(['col2'])['vote'].transform(lambda x: x.unique().sum())

df
#  col1  col2  vote  aggrVote
#0    a     2     5         7
#1    a     2     5         7
#2    b     2     2         7
#3    c     4     1         1
#4    d     3     5         5
#5    d     3     5         5
#6    d     3     5         5
```

Comment: the @anky_91 option is very fast. The all in one solution posted by zipa is ok but slower. Thanks to both :)